# Why does my projects in SonarQube get deleted automatically when I scan a new project?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am wondering why our SonarQube projects get deleted when we scan another project.

I have 10 projects already analysed and when I scan another one, it stays as 10 projects analysed. When I look, I see that there was one project deleted and the new one analysed was added.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [edit] your question to include details about the new and deleted projects such as the value used for `sonar.projectKey`, as well as whether the missing project was actually deleted or merely _replaced_ by the new project.

Comment: I just saw why, it was because the groupId and the artifactId was the same on both projects. Thank you for your help I really appreciate it!